# Woocommerce RestAPI not working properly 401 Error code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I've been trying to Get products details from my existing wordpress woocomerce website. I have created the Key and able to get data when use $woocommerce->get('') but when use $woocommerce->get('orders') or $woocommerce->get('products') it's giving 401 error.

Following is my code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    
    'https://mycustomdomain.com', 
    'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        'query_string_auth' => true,
    ]
);


    $results = $woocommerce->get('orders');
    //$results = $woocommerce->get('');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre>";
```

I have also uninstalled all the plugins and upgraded the PHP version to the latest one and also, increased the memory which is now 256m but nothing works properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
//maybe if you change this:

[
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        'query_string_auth' => true,
]

// enter code here

to this:

[
        'wp_api' => false,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        'query_string_auth' => false,
]
```